# Python to Windows Executable under Wine

Tags: python, py2exe, wine, tryton

Has anyone successfully created a Windows executable file using [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/FrontPage), [cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/) or [Pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) under [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/) from a Linux machine?

My goal is to be able to just push the code to a gitolite repository Ubuntu server then a git-hook will build the exe for windows and publish them for distribution. I've tried using cx_Freeze to no avail; pyinstaller seems to work but needs pywin32 which crashed during installation in wine.

If someone has successfully done so, how did you do it and did you have to install all the Python modules that were required by the application to be "compiled" for the wine-python installation? The specific application for which I want a windows exe is the [Tryton Client](http://www.tryton.org/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

Acсording to [py2exe wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Py2Exe), it produces invalid Win32 executables.

Comment: It indeed does produce invalid binaries.